# Access components local state in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How to access components local state in mapStateToProps ?
like ownProps , but local state this time.

Comment: Can you brief what actually you wish to acheive

Comment: const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    MyGlobalValue: state.someValue.fiter(GET VALUE FROM COMP. LOCAL STATE)
}

using components state value in this function.

Comment: That's what I'm asking you use `mapStateToProps` to access store data in Component where you specify this `mapStateToProps` in connect Right? if it is local then you have direct access to your state using `this.state`

Comment: I couldn't understand you , mapStateToProps function is not a member function of my class component , how I can access this.state inside of that function?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. You can pass the someValue to the component and already there, filter it.

Comment: Yes , this is one of the things I will do if I can't find more elegant soulution.
Are you sure it is impossible